# Python: multiple possible values for function arguments

Tags: python, boolean-expression

I've inherited some Python code that looks like this:

```
name = 'London'
code = '0.1'
notes = 'Capital of England'
ev = model.City(key=key, code=code, name=name or code, notes=notes)
```

In the spirit of learning, I'd like to know what's going on with the `name or code` argument. Is this saying 'Use `name` if it's not null, otherwise use `code`'?

And what is the technical term for supplying multiple possible arguments like this, so I can read up on it in the Python docs?

Thanks!

Comment: my bad - edited, sorry. gotta stop using pseudocode!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Almost. It says *use name if it does not evaluate to false*. [Things that evaluate to false](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) include, but are not limited to:

- `False`
- empty sequences (`(), [], ""`)
- empty mappings (`{}`)
- 0
- `None`

**Edit** Added the link provided by [SilentGhost](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12855/silentghost) in his comment to the answer.

Comment: [full list is available in docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

Comment: @AP257 in terms of where to look in the Python docs, give this section a read: http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations

Answer (score 7):

In python, the `or` operator returns the first operand, unless it evaluates to false, in which case it returns the second operand.  In effect this will use `name`, with a default fallback of `code` if `name` is not specified.

Comment: The clarification that `or` returns actual values of its operands, and not mere `True` or `False` is very important, both for general education and as an answer to the original question

Answer (score 2):

Correct, that idiom take the first value that evaluates to True (generally not None). Use with care since valid values (like zero) may inadvertently be forsaken. A safer approach is something like:

```
if name is not None:
  # use name
```

or

```
name if name is not None else code
```

Answer (score 1):

Fire up a Python console:

```
>>> name = None
>>> code = 0.1
>>> name or code
0.10000000000000001
```

In case name evaluates to false the expression will evaluate to code. Otherwise name will be used.

Answer (score 1):

> In the spirit of learning, I'd like to
>   know what's going on with the name or
>   code argument. Is this saying 'Use
>   name if it's not null, otherwise use
>   code'?

yes basically but Null in python can mean more than one thing (empty string , none ..)

like in your case:

```
>>> name = 'London'
>>> code = 0.1
>>> name or code
'London'
>>> name = ''
>>> code = 0.1
>>> name or code
0.1000....
```

but it weird thew that a function parameter can be integer sometimes and a string other times.

Hope this can help :=)

Comment: To avoid confusion, I would say this is not an example of default parameter values, it's just evaluation of boolean expressions. Default parameter values are when you provide a default value in the method *definition* e.g. `def some_method(param1, some_flag = False): # some_flag defaults to False if omitted at call time`. Also, as others have said, it is falseness rather than null that the empty string, empty list etc. evaluate to.

Comment: @mikej: i understand from his question __multiple possible arguments like (this)__ that he is talking about __default argument values__ maybe i misunderstood that :) because it depend on the __this__ this for the function or for the or ???

Comment: I think @AP257 (the OP) is thinking that the `name or code` is some kind of special parameter passing syntax when really it is evaluation of expressions and can be used anywhere that an expression can be.

Comment: @mikej: hmmm yes maybe you're right , thanks for the correction :) i will reedit

Answer (score 0):

You've it it roughly correct, but 'null' is not precisely what decides.  Basically anything that will evaluate to false (0, false, empty string '') will cause the second string to be displayed instead of the first.  'x or y' in this sense is kind of equivalent to:

if x: x
else: y

Some console play:

> > > x = ''
> > >       y = 'roar'
> > >       x or y
> > >       -'roar'
> > >       x = 'arf'
> > >       x or y
> > >       -'arf'
> > >       x = False
> > >       x or y
> > >       -'roar'